# Is it a bad idea to host multiple sites on one Apache server?

Tags: apache, web

Title pretty much explains it. I've been told this is a bad idea before by a buddy, are they correct? It's one dedicated server with multiple domain names forwarding to different sites on said server. Is this something I should avoid doing, or are there going to be major security concerns?

Comment: It's perfectly fine.

Comment: What would make someone think this is bad, out of curiosity? How would someone get to thinking that this is the case?

Comment: Well, the security concern is that they probably have some level of access to each other and might go down together, but that's pretty much what you'd expect. There are no unpleasant surprises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It not inherently a bad idea but there are things to take into consideration.

- How powerful is your server?
- How much traffic do expect to serve?
- Will your site be resource intensive?

If you have a minimal server hosting sites where you expect a large amount of traffic, then you may not want to host multiple sites on a single server, but if you have a decently powered server and expect a moderate amount of traffic; hosting multiple sites should be fine.

If you site is going be running resource intensive processes you should certainly consider the power of your server.

Apache is actually designed to host multiple sites using virtual hosts. Here's some guides on setting up virtual hosts on Apache.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-serve-multiple-domains-using-virtual-hosts

I've run single server configurations that host approximate 20 sites without issue. If you're concerned with server scalability, a better option is two identical servers behind a load balancer so you can simply add additional servers to handle increases in traffic.